# Object model for .NET for the (SQL Server Reporting Services) .RDLC files?

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, object-model

We are looking at doing some transformations and in-flight editing of reports during report execution, using the Local Report system in .NET.

Is there a better object model somewhere than the one produced by XSD, XSDCodeGen or XSD2CODE,
for .RDLC files?

It seems they all indicate that the first level of objects inside the report is just a collection of `object` objects. This makes it really cumbersome to write any code, and we're thinking that we might be better off just doing manual XML code for this.

Comment: I'm wondering if you came up with a solution for this?  If so, please post an answer.

Comment: Nope, never did, we picked a different set of reporting components in the end, built by [DevExpress](http://devexpress.com).

Answer (score 0):

I have also had to handle dynamic reports some time ago and have been looking for an object model, but it seems there isn't any.

Therefore, go for the XML, or create some very light object model of yourself that would serialize into the RDLC XML; luckily there's this option to bind the report source to any XML content.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlObjectModel.dll

According to [Professional Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services](http://tinyurl.com/c4ruwb6)